# Make elastic search return only field_names matchig my query

Tags: elasticsearch-query

I am using elastic query search to query my database.
In my database there will be different objects and each objects will have field_names. 
If I give any keyword as my query, I am getting all the objects having any field_name matching my query. This includes other field_names of that particular object too.
My question is is there any way, to retrieve objects with only field_names to which my query is getting matched.
Example say attributes of my objects are `["first name", "last name", "city"]`. Suppose my object Obj1 has first name as "ABC" and my object Obj2 has city as "ABC". Now when I give any query string "ABC", the result should be similar to this.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "first_name": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "city": "ABC"
    }
  ],
  "result_count": 2,
  "cursor": "2"
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. If you are doing search across all fields across multiple indices without providing the selected field names, then by default, it will always return all fields available on the matched document. Better approach will be to limit the search to select fields that makes more sense and leverage the highlighting feature so that you can use it to display which part of text matched.

With highlighting, you can add custom HTML/CSS tags. Please check below documentation on highlighting.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-highlighting